# How to replace values in file using python's tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have such tuple [(x1,x12), (x2,x22), (x3,x32)..]. 
I also have txt file with unsorted code where x1, x2, x3... xn being met.

I want to replace in txt file values in such order: 
x1(old)--> x12 (new), x2(old) ---> x22(new)...

So... I have written such code:

```
gen = (x for x in df1 if x[0] != x[1])


for x in gen:

    with open(ei.txt) as f1:
    newText = [f1.read().replace(x[1], x[0])]

    with open(ei2.txt, "w") as f2:
    f2.write(newText)
```

But I have an error while processing it: Expected an indented block. 
What is wrong with a code?

Comment: The argument to `write` must be a string, not a list.

Comment: indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Expected an indented block. What is wrong with a code?

Correct your code indentation. It matters in python. Also add quotes around the text file names.

```
gen = (x for x in df1 if x[0] != x[1])

df = []


for x in gen:

    with open("ei.txt") as f1:
        newText = [f1.read().replace(x[1], x[0])]   # <-- Add four spaces

    with open("ei2.txt", "w") as f2:
        f2.write(newText)    # <-- Add four spaces
```

Comment: Perfect! I really have not thought that it could mean something. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be reading the file only once, applying all your changes, then writing the file out again.

```
replacements = [('x', 'y'), ('a', 'b')]

with open('ei.txt') as infile
    text = infile.read()

for target, replacement in replacements:
    text = text.replace(target, replacement)

with open('ei2.txt', 'w+') as outfile:
    outfile.write(text)
```

If all of your transformations replace a single character, you could use `str.translate`.

Comment: Thank you for a comment. It is very important mark for me.